# Conditionally load Sembast in place of Sqlite for web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, sqflite, sembast

I have a Flutter app which runs on both mobile (Android/iOS) and web. Until a few days ago it worked properly with Sqflite (mobile) and Sembast (web) using a common DatabaseContext base class and two specific implementations:

```
factory DatabaseContext.get() {
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    return MobileDatabaseContext();
  } else {
    return WebDatabaseContext();
  }
}
```

I switched from Sqflite to Sqlite_Async (based on Sqlite3) and now I get this error. I don't understand why, as `kInWeb` should compile only references to the web path.

```
Error: Dart library 'dart:ffi' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ffi';
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ffi' is imported through these packages:

    web_entrypoint.dart => package:xxx => package:sqlite_async => package:sqlite3 => dart:ffi
    web_entrypoint.dart => package:xxx => package:sqlite_async => package:sqlite3 => package:ffi => dart:ffi
    ...

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    web_entrypoint.dart => package:xxx/main.dart => package:xxx/notifier/locale.notifier.dart => package:xxx/services/configuration.service.dart => package:xxx/services/base.service.dart => package:xxx/data/database_context.dart => package:xxx/data/mobile/mobile_database_context.dart => package:xxx/data/mobile/book.repository.dart => package:xxx/data/mobile/base.repository.dart => package:sqlite_async/sqlite3.dart => package:sqlite3/sqlite3.dart => package:sqlite3/src/ffi/api.dart => dart:ffi
```

Any idea?